# Width for apex page block section

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I am using the apex pageblock and pageblocksection with lightning LDS. The page block section is not hiding the third column due to rendering issue. Below is the piece of code :

```
<apex:pageBlock >

        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" dataStyle="width:10%" labelStyle="width:23%" collapsible="false" >
         <apex:selectList value="{!selectedYear}" id="fy" label="Fiscal Year" tabIndex="1" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="slds-select">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!years}" />
                </apex:selectList>


                <apex:selectList id="region" value="{!selectedregion}" multiselect="false" size="1" label="Region" onclick="setPrevVal();"  onchange="showConfirm({!isEdit}, false);" required="true" styleClass="slds-select ">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!RegionList}"/>
                </apex:selectList>

                <apex:selectList id="month" value="{!selectedMonth}" multiselect="false"
                    size="1" label="Month" onclick="setPrevVal();" onchange="showConfirm({!isEdit}, false);" styleClass="slds-select">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!MonthList}" />
                </apex:selectList>

  <apex:selectList id="dsso" value="{!selectedDsso}" multiselect="false" disabled="{!if(selectedMonth == '0',true,false)}"
                                 size="1" label="DSSO" onclick="setPrevVal();" onchange="showConfirm({!isEdit}, true);" required="true" styleClass="slds-select">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!DssoList}" />
                </apex:selectList>
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedCategory}" id="cat" label="Category" tabIndex="1" multiselect="false" size="1" styleClass="slds-select">
                <apex:selectOptions value="{!categories}" />
                </apex:selectList>




                <apex:selectList id="tfsArea" value="{!selectedTfsAreaNumber}" multiselect="false" disabled="{!if(selectedDsso == '0',true,false)}"
                                 size="1" label="TFS Area Number" onclick="setPrevVal();" onchange="showConfirm({!isEdit}, false);" required="true" styleClass="slds-select">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!TFSAreaNumberList}" />
                </apex:selectList>



            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` inside `apex:pageBlockSection` to get proper formatting.

Example below:

```
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="3" 
        dataStyle="width:10%" 
        labelStyle="width:23%" 
        collapsible="false" >
        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
            <apex:outputLabel value="Fiscal Year"
                for="fy"/>
            <apex:outputPanel>
                <apex:selectList value="{!selectedYear}" 
                    id="fy"
                    tabIndex="1" 
                    multiselect="false" 
                    size="1" 
                    styleClass="slds-select">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!years}" />
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:outputPanel>
        </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

        <!-- ** add two more apex:pageBlockSectionItem** -->

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: If I am not wrong then the datastyle is not an attribute of pageblocksection , its of pageblocksection item. Also not got compatible for more than 3 item value

Comment: I just had copied it from your code, it had dataStyle so had assumed it was working. Can you elaborate the problem?

Comment: @cloudy Please do not try to censor other people's posts.